# Is there any difference in meaning between "apt to" and "likely to"?

Tags: meaning, differences, semantics

Just as there is a difference in meaning between "likely" and "liable" in terms of a desirable or undesirable outcome, is there any subtle diference between "apt" and "likely" ?

> Does the use of "apt to" and "likely to" in the following sentences convey the same degree of expectation ?
>
> - "John is apt to call on us on Wednesday afternoon."
> - "John is likely to call on us on Wednesday afternoon."
> - My dog is apt to run away if I don't close the gate.
> - My dog is likely to run away if I don't close the gate.

Comment: I think of *apt to* as more like *prone to* or *given to* while *likely to* refers more to probability.  In other words something that's apt to happen does so due to its inherent nature, something that's likely to happen does so from a probability perspective.  Of course, in practice, the probability or likelihood of occurrence is higher for things that are inherently apt to happen.

Comment: The two ideas are unrelated and not interchangeable.

Comment: Could you include the dictionary entries for the two words into the body of the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your examples, they are freely interchangeable without conveying different degrees of expectation (cf. *apt* definition 2 and *likely* definition 1 - both below). The main difference is that *apt*'s more popular definition (def. 1 *prone*) influences the connotation toward conveying a sense of inherent history and habit<sup>1</sup>, while *likely* isn't as strong in connoting past experience, stressing mere present probability.

So *"my dog is **apt** to run away if I don't close the gate"* tends toward *"my dog runs away most of the time when I leave the gate open"*, while *"my dog is **likely** to run away [...]"* sounds more like *"dogs run away when they can, so my dog probably will".* Note that this is a nuance, not a definite demarcation, so you can still use either in the exact same situation.

Dictionary.com entry for [apt](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/apt):

> **1.**
>   inclined; disposed; given; prone:
>   *too apt to slander others.*
>
> **2.** likely:
>   *Am I apt to find him at home?*
>
> **3.** unusually intelligent; able to learn quickly and easily:
>   *an apt pupil.*
>
> **4.** suited to the purpose or occasion; appropriate:
>   *an apt metaphor; a few apt remarks on world peace.*

Dictionary.com entry for [likely](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/likely):

> **1.** probably or apparently destined (usually followed by an infinitive):
>   *something not likely to happen.*
>
> **2.** seeming like truth, fact, or certainty; reasonably to be believed or expected; believable:
>   *a likely story.*
>
> **3.** seeming to fulfill requirements or expectations; apparently suitable:
>   *a likely place for a restaurant.*
>
> **4.** showing promise of achievement or excellence; promising:
>   *a fine, likely young man.*

---

I know you didn't ask for this part, but it hadn't struck me before that *apt* and *likely* have several definitions that are also quite similar to each other. And it does address the title!

*Apt* def. 3 is comparable to *likely* def. 4 (roughly *promising*), and mostly interchangeable, though less so than *apt* 2 and *likely* 1. *Apt* 3 is closer to *talented* (good at a specific objective, e.g. *an apt learner*, not usually *a likely learner*), where *likely* 4 is more generally positive (*a likely young man*, not usually *an apt young man* unless it's referring to his proficiency in a certain endeavor).

*Apt* 4 is comparable to *likely* 3 (roughly *suitable*), though they aren't quite interchangeable. *Apt* 4 is usually used for an action (an *apt apology*, but an *apt location* works too), where *likely* does not refer to an action (not a *likely apology*, but a *likely location* is fine). And where they overlap, there is a distinct difference. *Likely* 1 heavily influences *likely* 3 so that it connotes a favorable level of probability that the subject will suit (hence "apparently" suitable), where *apt* cuts to the chase and simply calls the subject suitable.

Note too that though I mentioned *apt* 1 earlier, it is not accurately replaced with *likely*, though [as Jim notes in a comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/190246/is-there-any-difference-in-meaning-between-apt-and-likely/190249#comment398059_190246), when something is prone to happen, its likelihood is increased.

Lastly, *likely* 2 is not semantically correlated with *apt* at all.

---

1: I found several discussions on these words by [googling *apt vs. likely*](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=apt%20vs%20likely#q=apt%20vs%20likely), and I really liked the way [grammar.com described *apt*](http://www.grammar.com/apt-likely-liable/): "The word ***apt*** typically suggests that the subject of the sentence has a natural tendency to enhance the probability of the outcome..."

Comment: !!! (great move)